# Android not showing launcher icon according to the screen densities

Tags: android, android-icons, screen-density

I have copy image in all formats (72x72,48x48,96x96,144x144,192x192) to their corresponding mipmap directories.But still i'm not getting the icon according to the screen density.What might be wrong or what should i do? Please help me.

Comment: "But still i'm not getting the icon according to the screen density" -- please explain **in detail** what you mean by this.

Comment: What i mean is that my screen density comes in xxxhdpi and i have put the image with 192x192 px for the same density as specified by android and even after this also the launcher icon comes in i think 144x144px.Ultimately it's not suitable for my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is you IDE? If you are using Android Studio then you should be able to see the added mipmap files in the res folder.

To create mipmap files from one image you must add an image asset by right clicking on the res folder. Then go to "New/Image Asset". You will be able to add a new launcher icon from here.

Comment: I tried this sir and it worked fine except that i couldn't set the background as transparent as i want a transparent background for the launcher.How may i do that?Thankyou

Comment: I believe you can only set the transparency in the image itself not within the android IDE. If you're using GIMP to create your images you may find this helpful: [gimp-using-web-transparency](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-web-transparency.html)